# Raspberry Pi3 BLE connecting/pairing error 111 connection refused

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm using a pair of Raspberry pi3 devices as BLE scanner and BLE beacon. I'd like to connect the beacon to the scanner. When trying to connect using Bluetooothctl or Bluetooth manager a Pass Key is generated in both the devices and getting connected then within a few seconds it gets disconnected. Also sometimes throwing connection refused 111 error.

Please help with this. The scanner is the Raspberry Pi3 B device and zero W is the Beacon.

Comment: It's seems like an error of configuration, because the connection is refused. Can you provide your code and/or the ip of the two hardware?

Comment: Can you please provide any link/guidelines to refer for this configuration?

Comment: Do you have btmon installed on your raspberry pi? If not, I highly recommend installing it and running it in the background as that should give you more information regarding what is happening.